# Does STS Need the RP Certificate Installed?

Tags: certificate, wif

I have a custom STS built with WIF.  If I have the Relying Party and STS on the same server, I can get it working.

However, I'm getting ID4036 errors when using a remote machine.  As I have dug into it, I found that by default in my STS was always encrpyting the outbound token with a local certificate rather than the certificate requested by the Relying Party.  One solution would be to install the certiicate used by the Relying Party (public key only) on the STS and code the STS to use that certificate.

However, that creates a problem as I add other Relying Parties on different servers.

Here's an Example:

STS on MySTS - signs tokens with SigningCert.

Relying Party on MyWebServer01 - wants to encrypt/decrypt with MyWebServer01Cert (owns public / private key)

I can install MyWebServer01Cert on MySTS and set the STS to use that for encrypting tokens, and everything should work.  However, let's say I want to add a Relying Party application to MyWebServer02.  It will not work unless I install the public and private key of MyWebServer01Cert.

I would think that you can simply transmit the public key to the STS and each RP can use it's own - somewhat like SSL.  Is this not the case?

Any help / suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, for encryption only the public key is needed. You actually never want to give away the private key of a certificate.

If you use the WS Federation protocol (usually used for STS scenarios on web sites) the request to the STS is not sent by your RP server, but by the browser of the user. I doub't that you call tell the browser to use the public key of the previous site for communication over https. The encrypted token on the other hand is decrypted by the rp server (meaning that the RP server must know the private key of the certificate used to encrypt the token).

Taking this circumstances into account I am pretty much sure that the public key of the certificate of the RP must be present on the STS and can not be included in the request. Everything else would probably be a dirty hack only working with your custom STS (e.g. including the public key as a paramter).

At least for "passive sign-in" scenarios. For WCF you could attach the certificate of your server as client certificate to your request. But I haven't tried this by myself.

Comment: Thanks, I believe you're correct as well.  I have some other issues, but they probably deserve their own thread.